# Set some grub unprotected

Tags: password, grub, access-control

Im trying to set an administration password to just some of the entries of the grub.So far I manage to set a password to every entry to the grub by editing the `/etc/grub/01_users files`. So now, I need to configure some of the entries to not ask for credentials. Apparently there's the option `--unprotected`, but i just don't know where should I place it.

Answer (score 1):

Each menu entry that you want to release for "the public" needs this entry. There's quite good explanation in the [Red Hat System Admin Manual](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-GRUB_2_Password_Protection.html). So, in essence search for lines in `/boot/grub.cfg` containing `menuentry` and add `--unrestricted`, e.g.

```
menuentry 'OS with unrestricted access' --unrestricted {
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, grub does not yet offer anything beyond editing the output of `grub-mkconfig` manually.

Comment: yes, but in which file?Because my 40_custom is empty

Comment: you have to edit `/boot/grub.cfg`. See my edit.

Comment: Dont think thats a good idea.That file is rewritten every time the grub is updated.

Comment: I know. Yet, there is currently no other way (known to me). You may script your edit if the menu entries under consideration have unique strings that you can search for.